# Should I be using a WPF user control? Or just a Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, menu, grid

So I have an application that is split into 2 parts - on the left there is a custom menu, on the right a grid that holds all the "content" (different screens).

It looks something like this:

[image]

Also, when the different buttons are hit, the menu on the left will fill up with different buttons (for example, if you hit the review button, the menu would become something along the lines):

```
Start Date
End Date

Employee
Project
...
```

I am pretty sure that I want each of the screens (to go on the right) to be their own user controls.

But my question is this: Should each of the menu's be user controls? This makes it a little harder to use them. Then I have to worry about having getters/setters so the main window can listen on the menu's buttons, etc.

The other option is to just programmatically add the buttons in the mainWindow, this way I can just add the listeners right in mainWindow.cs (into a grid)

Which is the better method? Or is there another method which is favoured?

Comment: WPF is designed for main use of Grid and Canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire window can be done easily as a `Grid`.

The left side can just hold a `StackPanel` or other layout control with your buttons.

You can use a `ContentPresenter` to hold the content on the right.  When you trigger your buttons, just change the bound content, and it will update with your appropriate user controls.

Comment: That sounds interesting. So you are saying I shouldn't have a separate file for each screen? But doesn't that mean that my MainWindow.cs/xaml files will be huuuuge?

Comment: @Toadums No - you can have a separate UserControl per "screen" - a ContentPresenter can swap otu the content at runtime.

Comment: ohhh, ok. I get it!! So it is ok to just define buttons in c# code, adding/removing them from the stackpanel?

Comment: @Toadums If you need to - though I'd tend to try to do something a little more elegant.  You can't just define them in xaml?

Comment: I could, I could have them each in their own panel/stackpanel, then when a button is hit, I change the panel which is being displayed in the menu. Is that a better way?? (I know all the buttons before runtime)

Comment: @Toadums just put the buttons in your main window, and change out the other user control

Comment: The thing is, when I click one of the buttons on the main menu (like shown in the picture), the MENU changes also, so I need to load all new buttons INTO THE MENU in place of the old buttons.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13185/discussion-between-toadums-and-reed-copsey)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might do it with a grid as Reed told. But if you will need to reuse this in another place, I think you should use a separated UserControl instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but I would use a `TabControl`, with `TabStripPlacement="Left"`.

If you need extra space on the left to display other stuff, you can override the default TabControl's `ControlTemplate` and add a bunch of margin space to the `TabPanel` inside the `ControlTemplate`. Alternatively, you could have the `TabItem`'s header display differently when it is selected versus when it is not selected.